# CreateDirectory creates Duplicate Directory in Public Folder

Tags: c#, windows, file-io

I have a Winforms application that is supposed to create a subdirectory in the **Public Documents** folder if the directory does not exist and save a text file to it.  However, if the subdirectory does not exist, it actually creates another directory called Public Documents under "C:/Users/Public" rather than just creating a subdirectory under the existing "C:/Users/Public" folder.  (In the example below the subdirectory is the variable 'token'.)  So I end up with 2 folders called Public Documents:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
        if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        {

            subPath = @"C:\Users\Public\Public Documents\" + token + @"\Tests\";

        }
        else if (result == DialogResult.No)
        {
            subPath = @"C:\Users\Public\Public Documents" + @"\Tests\";
        }
        TestModel testCall = new TestModel
        {
            Name = frm.fileName,
            MethodName = txtApiMethod.Text,
            Parameter = rtxtJson.Text,
            SchemaKey = txtSchemaKey.Text
        };
        bool exists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(subPath);
        string fileName = frm.fileName + ".txt";
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testCall);
        string filePath = subPath + fileName;
        if (!exists)
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subPath);
        }
        using (StreamWriter file = File.CreateText(filePath))
        {
            file.Write(json);

        }
```

Can someone tell me why it is creating a duplicate named directory, and what I can do to have just create a new subdirectory under the existing directory?

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you debugged what exists is returning? According to Microsoft documentation if you dont have the right privileges, this will always return false, and that would make you create a new directory. Try executing your program as administrator

Comment: You are correct.  When testing just for the public directory "            bool exists2 = System.IO.Directory.Exists(@"C:\Users\Public\Public Documents\");" It returns false.  I thought the the public directory was supposed to have shared read/write permissions and did not require administrator.  Would that not cause any issue then as every user is not going to be an administrator?

Comment: I think @Cid is on the right track, while what i told you was true, the fact that it is the public folder means it should be accessible from anyone (administrator or not). The function returns false, if you dont have any privilege or the folder does not exists. I think you are pointing to a Link path, instead of the real path

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`C:\Users\Public\Public Documents` is a **display** name. I have a french Windows, and the display name is `C:\Users\Public\Documents publics`

The **real** path is `C:\Users\Public\Documents`

Display :

[image: Screenshot showing C:\Users\Public\Documents publics as display name]

Real :

[image: Screenshot showing C:\Users\Public\Documents as real path]

To make sure you are using the correct folder path (for some reasons, `d:` could be used instead, or the path could be totaly different. **Never use hardcoded path**), you can use `System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);` that links to `C:\Users\Public\Documents`, such as :

```
var PublicDocuments = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonDocuments);
if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    subPath = PublicDocuments + @"\"+ token + @"\Tests\";
}
else if (result == DialogResult.No)
{
    subPath = PublicDocuments + @"\Tests\";
}
```

See the documentation for more infos about [`System.Environment.SpecialFolder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8) and [`System.Environment.GetFolderPath()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath?view=netframework-4.8)